# Cannot query property named "group" on EF object

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have an EF entity object `sysSettings` class that has a few properties. `group` and `name` is among these properties.

`quer` in the code below is an `IQueryable<sysSettings>` object.

When trying to write the following query, I'm having difficulty with the second where clause.

```
var query = from setting in quer
    where (setting.name.Equals("Url") && setting.group.Equals("system"))
select setting;
```

It seems that when I have a property on an Entity object called `group` I cannot access that property from within the LINQ query.

I think this might be because `group` may be a reserved/contextual work/action in LINQ.

Changing the property name of the Entity is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: What is the error message and what component is giving that message?

Comment: it tries to use `group` from linq and not group from the entity. Seems like the `Equals(string)` method is not available even though `group` is a string property.

Comment: Please post the message and originator of the message. It is the best tool to diagnose and provide a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `@` symbol to your property name (only for query, do not change settings class definition):

```
var query = from setting in quer
            where (setting.name.Equals("Url") && setting.@group.Equals("system"))
            select setting;
```

This symbol allows you to to use reserved word (which is `group`).

Answer (score 1):

What if you write in fluent syntax?

```
var query = quer.Where(e => e.name.Equals("Url") &&
                            e.group.Equals("system"));
```